# Dynamic user controls preserve state on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm having a hard time facing a problem with dynamic user controls in ASP.NET Web Forms (I know they suck, but my project relies on them). So briefly my case is:

1. I have a DropDownList in my aspx page with several options to select
   from (for each one, I have different User control to render);
2. When I select one, the user control for this option is rendered below in a placeholder inside UpdatePanel:

[image]

1. In code behind in DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged method I create instance of the user control using Page.LoadControl(string virtualPath) and then I add it to the controls of placeholder:

   ```
   selectedFilters.Controls.Add(myUserControlObject);
   ```

The first user controls renders ok, but when I try to add new user control to the placeholder, the first user control disappears and only the new user control is rendered. How can I preserve the state of the whole user controls objects so during postback they don't become lost?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add each dynamically added control on every postback, which is usually best done in the Page_PreLoad event so that the dynamically added control will return to it's last state based on ViewState and posted values.

You can use ViewState to store which controls have been added. How you would do this depends on your circumstances but it could be something like this, which you would do when you dynamically add a control:

```
ViewState["DynamicControl1"] = true;
```

And then in your Page_PreLoad event...

```
if ((bool)ViewState["DynamicControl1"])
{
    //Add your control again here,
    //possibly duplicated from your DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged handler
}
```

Depending on your ViewState settings, ASP.NET will repopulate your DropDownList item list and selected value automatically as long as the control is added in the right part of the page lifecycle. If you have disabled ViewState then you will need to repopulate your list items when you add the control in the Page_PreLoad event.

Note that it can be important that the dynamically added control has the same ID each postback so if you have issues try setting ClientIDMode to "AutoID".